# I am getting CORS errors despite setting PHP headers and .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess, cors

I have had a lot of success securely allowing CORS but I have tried with another page and it's not working. I hope someone can tell me what I'm missing.  I know that * is insecure, but I'm trying that just to eliminate the site name as a variable.

.htaccess file

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

and the top of my php file:

```
// Allow from any origin just for testing...
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
    // in production, no *, but using my real domain
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');
}
// Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");         

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

}
```

When accessing the php file with an ajax request, I receive:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://sitename.000webhostapp.com/' from origin 'https://samesitename.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

It works in Postman. Here is header info:

```
Date →Mon, 29 Apr 2019 18:50:03 GMT
Content-Type →text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding →chunked
Connection →keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin →*
Access-Control-Allow-Headers →origin, x-requested-with, content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods →PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
Server →awex
X-Xss-Protection →1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options →nosniff
X-Request-ID →18341eb6e5c7e5f483d8dd3a3a492b9c
Content-Encoding →gzip
```

The bigger story is that I'm hosting the main site on firebase which doesn't support PHP, so I put the php files on 000webhostapp.com as a workaround.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear; there is no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the response for requests to `https://sitename.000webhostapp.com/`. Is the host configured to support `.htaccess` files? You can also test with curl or Postman to inspect the headers, eg `curl -v -o /dev/null -H "Origin: http://localhost" "https://sitename.000webhostapp.com/"`

Comment: The clarity of the error message is the problem. As I said, I've fixed this issue before.  And as you can see, there IS an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header present.  It works fine with Postman. I've added the header dump to the question.  Thanks!

Comment: If it says it’s not there, it’s not there when the request is made. There’s no magic in this mechanism. The header has to be present for the preflight OPTIONS request, not actual script.

Comment: I find a lot of issues are resolved like this on stackoverflow, but I still haven't learned my lesson. I had a typo in the "https://sitename.000webhostapp.com/" part of the request. I wasn't pointing to a file!  It should be: "https://sitename.000webhostapp.com/php/mail.php"

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes across this post with a similar issue, my resolution was to double check the url!!!

I posted that I was checking

```
https://sitename.000webhostapp.com/
```

when I was supposed to reference

```
https://sitename.000webhostapp.com/php/mail.php
```

Thanks to @Phil and @emix for forcing me to check the details.